# Minor Plaster Damage - Should I Use structo-lite or drywall joint compound? (3 small cases)

Tags: drywall, walls, plaster

Anyone have any experience with the best ways to approach these 3 plaster scenarios.  Small 1950's bungalow.  I have structo-lite base coat here with me and can also use joint compound where drywall mud makes sense.

Pic 1:  small kitchen wall.  Previous owner glued laminate backslash to plaster wall...and it pulled off these 4 or 5 circles.  Doesn't seem that enough is gone to demo through to the lath to redo from there.  But maybe thats the only option.
[image]
[image]

Pic 2:   floating shelves on two walls.  When removed, anchors needed to come out and left smaller but deeper holes.
[image]

Pic 3:   Saw a strange plaster Crack by a back window and also some paint bubbling.  Could have been before maybe an issue was fixed outside.  Used a small knife and got the original and maybe second different coat of paint.  But none of the wall is removed.  So to me, floating drywall mud makes more sense.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd get a bag of plaster and mix it up. It will dry harder than regular joint compound and is easier to work with over larger areas. It also dries faster than joint compound so you can finish up faster. You mentioned some other types of plaster patch but mixing up the dry stuff just seems better. Use a big knife for the wall in the first picture for smoothing out purposes.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  So I think I know this answer, but we are saying that structo-lite in theory, is not plaster.  So to hit depot and just pick up the smallest bag of plaster they sell.  Mix and knife in.  Which I have all those tools.

Comment: That's correct, The advantage of plaster is it doesn't shrink  like a lot of the premixes do. I've never had to use mesh tape with plaster either.

Answer (score 0):

For those larger cracks

use self adhesive fiber mesh and plaster over it to avoid future problems

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I have plenty of mesh tape so that's a great suggestion over the Crack.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @J.P if you find my answer usefull show it